# I there a python function to reset the script after it's run?

Tags: python, string, integer, reset

So when i run this in my IDE, the terminal pops up and I input whatever, it oututs the way it's intended, but then the terminal closes. Is there a function that can simply reset the function in the terminal with the same code in order to simply keep entering things like a kind of game?

Also is there anyway for me to get the "<0" conditional to work properly? I need to convert the string back into a number in order for it to do that properly.

```
    # Rate our Love!! 
###   Press F5
## then input a rating for our relationship so far
print "Type a rating for our relationship" 
love_rate = raw_input()
### word answers
idk = 'idk'
no = 'no' 
yes = 'yes' 
lol = 'lol'
smh = 'smh'
def love(n):
    if n < 0 : 
        print "Why would it be negative?!" 
    elif n == 'yes' : 
        print " Well if that's the case, then I think we're gonna be just fine." 
    elif n == 'no' : 
        print 'well then... this is awkward'
    elif n == 'lol' : 
        print '''THATS NOT EVEN A NUMBER







        ......sniff'''
    elif n == 'smh' :
        print "I'm kinda mad that's an answer you thought of putting here"      
    ## numbered entries 
    elif n == '0' : 
        print " *gasps profusely* YOU DON'T DESERVE THIS PROGRAM" 
    elif n == '1' :
        print "Wow that is kinda hurtful, not gonna lie" 
    elif n == '2' : 
        print "You make me smile at least once, each and every day"
    elif n == '3' : 
        print"you wouldn't believe how annoying it was to get this program to run properly!" + " Thats all i get?"
    elif n == '4' : 
        print "let's " + "shoot a little higher than that"
    elif n == '5' : 
        print "you're unforgettable, that's what you are" 
    elif n == '6' :
        print "always have, always '____' *hint* fill in the blank " 
    elif n == '7' :
        print "i could never leave you, I love you too much" 
    elif n == '8' : 
        print "an 8/10 is still only a B, maybe I'm not trying hard enough" 
    elif n == '9' : 
        print " well, I'm not perfect yet, could have seen that one coming. Guess I just have to keep trying :)" 
    elif n == '10' : 
        print " i think you're exaggerating, i really am not that good yet"     
    elif n == '11' : 
        print """I can be a little immature sometimes and i'm sorry for that, i promise I can get better though. But i need you. I need you to help me out. Can you do that?""" 
    elif n == '12' : 
        print "I don't think the scale is supposed to go this high" 
    elif n == '13' :
        print "alright now you're pushing it." 
    elif n == '14' : 
        print "alright, THE SCALE GOES UP TO AROUND 10. CEASE" 
    elif n == '15' : 
        print " go up one more number. I DARE YOU"
    elif n == '16' : 
        print " go up one more number. see what happens"
    elif n == '17' : 
        print "one more number" 
    elif n == '18' : 
        print "one more" 
    elif n == '19' : 
        print "STOP" 
    elif n == '92412' : 
        print " I think that is one fantastic answer, can't wait for our anniversary" 
    else:
        print "I still really hope that we could get married someday." 
def reset_print():
    print """ 




Wanna Try Again? :D """ 
love(love_rate)
reset_print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything in a function and after you finish the script, you can add a Yes or No question, if the answer is yes you just call the function again.

```
import sys
def myScript():
        # Rate our Love!! 
    ###   Press F5
    ## then input a rating for our relationship so far
    print "Type a rating for our relationship" 
    love_rate = raw_input("Type a rating for our relationship:")
    ### word answers
    idk = 'idk'
    no = 'no' 
    yes = 'yes' 
    lol = 'lol'
    smh = 'smh'
    love(love_rate)

def love(n):
        if n < 0 : 
            print "Why would it be negative?!" 
        elif n == 'yes' : 
            print " Well if that's the case, then I think we're gonna be just fine." 
        elif n == 'no' : 
            print 'well then... this is awkward'
        elif n == 'lol' : 
            print '''THATS NOT EVEN A NUMBER    ......sniff'''
        elif n == 'smh' :
            print "I'm kinda mad that's an answer you thought of putting here"      
        ## numbered entries 
        elif n == '0' : 
            print " *gasps profusely* YOU DON'T DESERVE THIS PROGRAM" 
        elif n == '1' :
            print "Wow that is kinda hurtful, not gonna lie" 
        elif n == '2' : 
            print "You make me smile at least once, each and every day"
        elif n == '3' : 
            print"you wouldn't believe how annoying it was to get this program to run properly!" + " Thats all i get?"
        elif n == '4' : 
            print "let's " + "shoot a little higher than that"
        elif n == '5' : 
            print "you're unforgettable, that's what you are" 
        elif n == '6' :
            print "always have, always '____' *hint* fill in the blank " 
        elif n == '7' :
            print "i could never leave you, I love you too much" 
        elif n == '8' : 
            print "an 8/10 is still only a B, maybe I'm not trying hard enough" 
        elif n == '9' : 
            print " well, I'm not perfect yet, could have seen that one coming. Guess I just have to keep trying :)" 
        elif n == '10' : 
            print " i think you're exaggerating, i really am not that good yet"     
        elif n == '11' : 
            print """I can be a little immature sometimes and i'm sorry for that, i promise I can get better though. But i need you. I need you to help me out. Can you do that?""" 
        elif n == '12' : 
            print "I don't think the scale is supposed to go this high" 
        elif n == '13' :
            print "alright now you're pushing it." 
        elif n == '14' : 
            print "alright, THE SCALE GOES UP TO AROUND 10. CEASE" 
        elif n == '15' : 
            print " go up one more number. I DARE YOU"
        elif n == '16' : 
            print " go up one more number. see what happens"
        elif n == '17' : 
            print "one more number" 
        elif n == '18' : 
            print "one more" 
        elif n == '19' : 
            print "STOP" 
        elif n == '92412' : 
            print " I think that is one fantastic answer, can't wait for our anniversary" 
        else:
            print "I still really hope that we could get married someday." 

        print """Want to try again?"""
        yes = set(['yes','y', 'ye', ''])
        no = set(['no','n'])

        choice = raw_input().lower()
        if choice in yes:
           myScript()
        elif choice in no:
           sys.exit(0)
        else:
           sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'")
        myScript()



myScript()
```

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately, that left it not working at all for some reason

Comment: Didn't see there was another function, try it again.

Comment: this should work except put use `love_rate = raw_input("Type a rating for our relationship:")`

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `n < 0` wont work is because `raw_input` gives a string back   and `n < 0` needs an int to work because you cant tell if a number is bigger than a word to do what you want use `input` instead of `raw_input` because `input` will give you a int back and then on you're elif statements you can take off the quotes so that they're numbers

you probably didnt need that big long explanation but whatever

what you could do is

```
n = raw_input("Rate Relationship: ")

if '-' in n:
    print ("Why would it be Negative!?")
```

Comment: the problem with that is when i use input the word answers won't work. It's not like the word answers are that necessary but i'm honestly curious if there's a way to do this

Comment: well yeah i guess you could but i dont really know how

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap everything in functions and simply call them recursively depending on a users input.

Example - just add these two functions to your program, rather than having all the logic in one massive function:

```
import sys

def main():
    print "Type a rating for our relationship" 
    love_rate = raw_input()
    love(love_rate)
    try_again()

def try_again()    
    print "Want to try again? [y]"
            yes_list = ['yes','y', 'ye', '', yeah]
            no_list = ['no','n']
            # Lower case it to normalise it
            answer = raw_input().lower()
            if answer in yes_list:
               main()
            elif answer in no_list:
               sys.exit(0)
            else:
               sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'")
            try_again()
```

1. There are a couple of ways to convert your string to a number to get it to work:

   1. Add a `try`, `except` block that converts your input to an integer. This will try and covert the input into an integer, and just leave it as it is if it can't. It does mean you will have to change your `elif` statements though; so they compare integers, rather than an integer and a string.
   2. Use a `regex` to detect the presence of a negative integer, and convert it accordingly.

`try`, `except` example:

```
try:
    love_rate = int(love_rate)
except ValueError:
    pass

def love(n):
        if n < 0 : 
            print "Why would it be negative?!" 

        # ....
        # Note the lack of ''
        elif n == 9 : 
            print " well, I'm not perfect yet, could have seen that one coming. Guess I just have to keep trying :)"
```

`regex` example:

```
import re

negative_integer_regex = re.compile(r'^(-\d+)$')
matching_negative_integer = negative_integer_regex.match(love_rate)
if matching_negative_integer:
    love_rate = int(matching_negative_integer.groups(1))
```